# Ubuntu symbolic link going to source location when up folder

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

The problem is the following - I`ve created a symbolic link to a folder /home/user1/folder1 in /home/user2/. When user2 follows this link, he comes to the /home/user1/folder1, but when he goes up folder he comes to /home/user1/ not /home/user2/. Is it possible to change this behavior?

Comment: I don't think so. Hardlinking a folder with `ln -d` or `ln -F` is not permitted on Ubuntu, even for sudo. There is a discussion about this [here](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/newbie/149236-creating-hard-link-directory.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. Solved by `mount --bind`